# Dell E2009W monitor not detected

Tags: monitor, x11

I have an issue with my monitor.

I just installed Ubuntu 11.10, but the monitor that is plugged in doesn't appear anywhere. And by doesn't appear, I mean that in the "Displays" menu, it doesn't even appear as "Unknown", I just have my screen that appears and nothing else.

It is connected through VGA, and the monitor is recognized with no problem on Windows 7. It is a Dell monitor.

I'm not a pro with Ubuntu, so any help to diagnose the issue would be really helpful (and help me learn how to fix this kind of monitor issue in the future)

Thanks !

Comment: The model is Dell E2009W

Comment: Actually when I look at the display and try to get in the menu it says that there is no signal coming from my computer... while it works fine when I just boot on Windows 7 !

Comment: What graphics card do you have? Did you install the proprietary drivers in Windows and not in Ubuntu?

Comment: I have attached my lspci result below, not sure about the graphics card, I did install some NVidia drivers though

Comment: You need to stop posting non-answers as answers below. The Answers section is for people that have an answer to your question, not for your responses to when people ask you for specific info.

Comment: @Charles - please do not use the answers section or comments to add further information.  The way this site works is to keep re-editing your question with new information.  I have done this for you this time.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First try installing (if You didn't do it) drivers. For example in case if these are nVidia drivers You will have to configure Your monitor trough

```
sudo nvidia-settings
```

and not trough system->preferencs->monitors.

If that fails delete Your xorg.conf file and create a new one.

Comment: That may sounds stupid, but how do you check which drivers you have installed, and how do you know which ones you're missing? I don't have a nvidia-settings command available, what am I missing? It would be great if I could get some assistance in the process, I'm not very familiar with Ubuntu. Thanks.

Comment: After installing a few things I finally got nvidia-settings, but I get an error message "You do not appear to be using the NVIDIA X driver.  Please edit your X configuration file (just run `nvidia-xconfig` as root), and restart the X server."

Comment: When running nvidia-xconfig as root, here is what I get "Using X configuration file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf".

VALIDATION ERROR: Data incomplete in file /etc/X11/xorg.conf.
                  Device section "Default Device" must have a Driver line.

Backed up file '/etc/X11/xorg.conf' as '/etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup'
New X configuration file written to '/etc/X11/xorg.conf'
" Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Here is what my xorg.conf looked like befoe nvidia-xconfig wrote its own : Section "Device"
 Identifier "Default Device"
 Option "NoLogo" "True"
EndSection

Comment: Interestingly enough, nvidia-detector returns me "none", while in my lspci results i can see a nVidia GF106. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Charles can you put this information in your question instead of buried in the comments? It will make it easier to understand, thanks!

Comment: Ok, maybe please try to install drivers for Your card not trough Software center, but rather by downloading them and using sudo NVIDIAFILENAME.run

Answer (score 0):

Open up jockey (Additional Drivers) on your computer and let it detect if you are missing any drivers. It will also let you know if you are currently using proprietary graphics drivers (which is sounds like you aren't), and allow you to install them if necessary. Once this is done, reboot the machine.

After it starts back up, open up the NVidia control panel and see if it detects your monitor correctly